# How to handle custom code in Ngsw - in Fetch event

Tags: angular, service-worker, ngsw-config

I was having service worker implemented in angular.js application where we have some custom code written in `self.addEventListener('fetch', function (event)` . Now i am planning to migrate the application to angular, and i found in angular we have the special plugin which will do all configuration and cache cleanup.  `"@angular/service-worker": "~10.0.6",`.

Now i am suffering to have the custom code implemented inside fetch event to integrate in angular version. Is there any way we can have the fetch method override in to a component and do the operation from there.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your message this steps were done using **angular-cli@10.0.6**.

## Edit service worker file.

- Open the file `<project_name>/node_modules/@angular/service-worker/ngsw-worker.js`
- Search `handleFetch function` Line 1121.
- Edit adapt that function with your requirement. Check out `handleFetchWithFreshness` and `handleFetchWithPerformance` as examples.
- Save

## Patch file

- Use [patch-package](https://github.com/ds300/patch-package) to save patch.`npx patch-package @angular/service-worker`
- Make a commit.
- Add `postinstall script` to `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
 "postinstall": "patch-package"
}
```

- Add `patch-package` package `npm install --save-dev patch-package`

## Test service worker

- ng build.
- start a server of dist files.
- it should works.